# SQL count function wont work properly in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am working in my final exam project using VB.NET and SQL SERVER 2005 platform. 
I need to detect the conflict when I select a specific date or time if it has in between in the database.

I already have my sql query in sql server and it works well. but when I was going to execute it in my vb.net project the problem starts to appear. I'm having a hard time with this. Any help will be appreciated.

myTable

```
Item            DateFrom             DateTo             TimeFrom              TimeTo
Diamond        3/10/2013           3/20/2013              NULL                 NULL
Cooler         3/10/2013           3/20/2013              NULL                 NULL
Cooler         3/21/2013              NULL             9:30:00 AM            11:00:00 AM 
Diamond        3/21/2013              NULL             8:00:00 AM            9:30:00 AM
```

mySQL

```
select count(*) from myTable
where '3/21/2013' between(datefrom)and(dateto) and item = 'Diamond'
or datefrom = '3/21/2013'  and timefrom between '8:00 AM' and '10:00 AM' and item = 'Diamond'
or datefrom = '3/21/2013' and  timeto between '8:00 AM' and '10:00 AM'   and item = 'Diamond'
or datefrom = '3/21/2013' and '8:00 AM' between(timefrom)and(timeto) and item = 'Diamond'
```

Result: 1

here's my vb.net code

```
SQLQUERY = "Select Count(*) as Conflicts from myTable" & _
     "Where '" & dtpTFrom.Value & "' between(datefrom)and(dateto) and item = '" &     cmbItems.Text & "'" & _
     "Or (datefrom = '" & dtpTFrom.Value & "'  and timefrom between '" &    Format(CDate(cmTFrom.Text), "hh:mm tt") & "' and '" & Format(CDate(cmTTo.Text), "hh:mm tt")      & "' and item = '" & cmbItems.Text & "')" & _
     "Or (datefrom = '" & dtpTFrom.Value & "' and  timeto between '" & Format(CDate(cmTFrom.Text), "hh:mm tt") & "' and '" & Format(CDate(cmTTo.Text), "hh:mm tt") & "'  and item = '" & cmbItems.Text & "')" & _
 "    Or (datefrom = '" & dtpTFrom.Value & "' and '" & Format(CDate(cmTFrom.Text), "hh:mm tt") & "' between(timefrom)and(timeto) and item ='" & cmbItems.Text & "')"

com = new sqlcommand(SQLQUERY,con) 
dr = com.ExecuteReader() 
dr.Read()
If dr.HasRows Then
    MsgBox(CInt(dr.GetValue(0)))
    If CInt(dr.GetValue(0)) > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Selected item is not available for that date and time.", AppTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

End If

msgbox result : 0

Comment: You say the problem is VB.NET, but you don't show the code. Could you post the VB.NET code that calls this query?

Comment: Oh sorry, 

here's my vb.net code

Comment: do you have any idea why i'm having that result? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to group your `OR` conditions by placing them inside a parenthesis, (*the reason why you are not getting incorrect result is because the conditions overlap with each other*)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   myTable
WHERE ('3/21/2013' BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto AND item = 'Diamond') OR
      (datefrom = '3/21/2013' AND timefrom BETWEEN '8:00 AM' AND '10:00 AM' AND item = 'Diamond') OR
      (datefrom = '3/21/2013' AND timeto BETWEEN '8:00 AM' AND '10:00 AM'   AND item = 'Diamond') OR
      (datefrom = '3/21/2013' AND '8:00 AM' BETWEEN timefrom AND timeto AND item = 'Diamond')
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 

i just applied your suggestion but still wont work in vb.net it returns a 0 value instead of 1.

Comment: In SQL Server, `AND` has higher priority than `OR`. After adding the parentheses as you are suggesting here, the order of evaluation of the individual simple conditions would remain same as in the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I need to post as an answer because code formatting in comment is not quite good.
Let me know if it works

```
com = new sqlcommand(SQLQUERY,con) 
Dim result = com.ExecuteScalar() 
if Convert.ToInt32(result) = 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Selected item is not available for that date and time.", ...)
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Also there is the problem of Parameters. You need to pass parameters to avoid SQL Injection, but also to be sure that strings like yours are correctly interpreted by the database engine as the dates required by the query

This is a rough translation of your query using parameters instead of a hand made string

```
SQLQUERY = "Select Count(*) as Conflicts from myTable " & _
     "Where @dateFrom  between(datefrom)and(dateto) and item = @item " & _
     "Or (datefrom = @dateFrom and timefrom between @timeFrom and @timeTo and item = @item) " & _
     "Or (datefrom = @dateFrom and   timeto between @timeFrom and @timeTo and item = @item) " & _
     "Or (datefrom = @dateFrom and @timeFrom between(timefrom)and(timeto)and item =@item)"

com = new sqlcommand(SQLQUERY,con) 
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom",  Convert.ToDateTime(dtpTFrom.Value))
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item",  cmbItems.Text)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeFrom",  Convert.ToDateTime(cmTFrom.Text))
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeTo",  Convert.ToDateTime(cmTTo.Text))
```

Comment: Hey Steve, your code doesn't work but you just gave an idea why i'm getting that problem and just like what you have said that i need to check my strings format I modified my code and it works pretty well like what i expected. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. When you find the correct format for the strings above, feel free to edit the answer to make it right (or if you don't have the permission, post another answer from yourself)

Comment: I used the FormatDateTime to dtpTFrom just like what you made in
com.Parameters.AddwithValue("@dateFrom", Convert.ToDateTime(dtpTFrom.value))

Comment: First i saw your rough translation to my code i got confused, and i read it slowly then found out that i have to convert my string to DateTime to be interpreted by the database engine.


Thanks for your reply guys.

Comment: First i saw your rough translation to my code i got confused, and i read it slowly then found out that i have to convert my string to DateTime to be interpreted by the database engine.


Thanks for your reply guys.